# C# IQueryable Contains with Multiple OR - Operator || can't be applied to operands of type 'bool'

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to have search functionality to my existing `IQueryable` object.

Here's my sample class:

```
public class Fruit {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Origin {get;set;}
    public List<string> Variations {get;set;}
}
```

and I map them to supply an IQuerayble object.

```
IQueryable<Fruit> fruits;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)){
    fruits = fruits.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(search) || x.Origin.Contains(search));
}
```

The above sample codes work fine. I was able to return those items depending on my search query.

But when I want to include the searching of `Variations`, then it doesn't work.

Here's the sample code that fails in the compiler.

```
fruits = fruits.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(search) || x.Origin.Contains(search) || x.Variations.Where(v=>v.Contains(search));
```

It shows the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0019  Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'IEnumerable<string>'
```

So far, I have tried this approach:

```
fruits = fruits.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(search) || x.Origin.Contains(search) || x.Variations.Contains(search));
```

But unfortunately, it returns all the list and it seems the search feature doesn't work at all.

Comment: `x.Variations.Any(v=>v.Contains(search))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `Where` on the query for variations returns results, rather than doing a conditional operation.  If you modify this to something similar to the following you should be ok.

```
fruits = fruits.Where(x => 
      x.Name.Contains(search) // Name contains the item
   || x.Origin.Contains(search) // Orgin Contains
   || x.Variations.Any(v => v.Contains(search)) // Any variation contains the search term
);
```